# Openlayers in Angular

Tags: angular, openlayers

I have a click function on an OpenLayers map

```
testvar: string
map = new Map()


ngOnInit(): void {

this.map.on('click', function(event) {
   console.log(this.testvar)
})

}
```

But `this` is not available within the scope of the click function.

Any ideas how to do this/

Comment: `let that = this; console.log(that.testvar)` not Sure but try like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because you declare your function using the `function` keyword.
If you declare you function as an arrow function, it will work:

```
this.map.on('click', event => {
   console.log(this.testvar)
})
```

Take a look at this article for more detail about arrow function vs function: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/when-and-why-you-should-use-es6-arrow-functions-and-when-you-shouldnt-3d851d7f0b26/

or this one: https://dmitripavlutin.com/differences-between-arrow-and-regular-functions/